# find next highest number in array - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a sorted array of numbers [2, 5, 12, 34, 56]
and a random number "17".
I need the index of the next highest number from my array. In this case i want to recieve "3" as it is the index of "34" which is the next highest number in my array.

any ideas?

Comment: Iterate and compare with the highest you found. That's all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A function that meets the requirements can be as simple as:

```
function getNextHighestIndex(arr, value) {
    var i = arr.length;
    while (arr[--i] > value);
    return ++i; 
}

getNextHighestIndex([2, 5, 12, 34, 56], 17);  // 3
getNextHighestIndex([2, 5, 12, 34, 56], 100); // 5
getNextHighestIndex([2, 5, 12, 34, 56], 0);   // 0
```

If there is no value in the array that is higher than the supplied value, it will return the length of the array. If all values in the array are higher, it will return 0.

Answer (score 6):

Running with vzwick's suggestion, you could do this quite neatly with [underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) `filter` and `indexOf` methods:

```
function getNextHighestIndex(arr, number) {
  return _.indexOf(arr, _.filter(arr, function(val) { 
    return val > number 
  })[0]);
}

getNextHighestIndex([2, 5, 12, 34, 56], 17);
```

Or vanilla JavaScript:

```
function getNextHighestIndex(arr, number) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    if (arr[i] > number) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

getNextHighestIndex([2, 5, 12, 34, 56], 17);
```

Comment: Since the input array appears to be pre-sorted, your vanilla solution isn't even overly brute force :)

Comment: How is plain JS "brute force"? It's just simple, efficient code.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it was in reference to @ewein's solution, which I'd only half read, in which he states that you can start the loop from the index of the random number. On closer inspection it's obvious that this is not in fact correct. Revised.

Answer (score 3):

This code will return the index you are looking for, and will return -1 if there is no number greater in the array.

```
function findNextHighest(array_input, compare_num){
    for (i=0;i<array_input.length;i++){
        if (array_input[i] > compare_num){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // Value returned if no highest number found in the array
}
```

Comment: +1 for a sensible "not found" return value. One tiny thing you might want to consider is that, in the JS world, names starting with a capital letter (such as *C*losestIndex) usually designate "Classes" that can (and should) be invoked with `new`. You might therefore want to name your function *c*losestIndex.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion vzwick. I edited it changing *C*losestIndex with findNextHighest

Answer (score 1):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/w42wE/3/ (click run)

```
var MyArray = [2, 5, 12, 34, 56]
var RandomNumber       = 17;
var MinGreaterThanPos;

for (var i =0; i < MyArray.length; i++) {
    if (MyArray[i] <= RandomNumber) 
        continue;

    if (typeof(MinGreaterThanPos) == 'undefined' || MyArray[i] < MinGreaterThanPos)
    { 
        MinGreaterThanPos = i;
    }
}

alert(MinGreaterThanPos);
```

Comment: I don't see no jQuery!! We've been flim–flammed!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray      = [2, 5, 12, 34, 56],
    randomNumber = 17;

var result = $(myArray)
    .map(function(i){ return (this > randomNumber) ? i : null })
    .get() // un-wraps the jQuery object to a proper Array
    .shift();
```

---

That being said, OP might want to look into [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) as a leaner alternative - honestly, jQuery is a bit of an overkill for the task.

Comment: +1 for functional solution.  `.first()` isn't standard JavaScript, though...do you polyfill that?  You could use `shift()` instead.

Comment: @EthanBrown Thanks for the pointer. I also forgot the `get()`. Ugh.

Comment: Ok, that does use jQuery. But [peformance absolutely sux](http://jsperf.com/nexthighestindex)!! Other solutions are more than 1,000 times faster.

Comment: @RobG - I never claimed that this was performant. As a matter of fact, I even recommended that OP look into underscore.js - JSPerf for the curious: http://jsperf.com/nexthighestindex/2 - instead of jQuery if they absolutely want to use a nifty library. That being said, nothing ever beats intelligently written vanilla stuff - and that's exactly what your solution is :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i=0; i<ary.length; i++;) {
  if (ary[i] > target) 
    return i;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something a bit more sophisticated, implement a divide&conquer search algorythm:

```
function find_next(list, query) {
    var pointer_upper = list.length - 1;
    var pointer_lower = 0;
    var pointer_tmp;
    while (pointer_upper - pointer_lower > 1) {
        pointer_tmp = Math.ceil((pointer_upper + pointer_lower)/2)
        if (list[pointer_tmp] <= query) {
            pointer_lower = pointer_tmp;
        } else {
            pointer_upper = pointer_tmp;
        }
    }
    return pointer_lower + 1;
}


find_next([2, 5, 12, 34, 56], 17); // returns 3
```

**Note**: it is possible that this function will return a result that is **less** then the `query` (if all the elements in `list` are less then `query)`. So maybe you would like to check for that before returning.